# Android ¿porque mi petición http get solo funciona bien solo cuando le hago debug?

Tags: android

Buen día.
Estoy realizando una petición http get, a esta le envió una cabecera de autorización, y funciona perfecto solamente cuando le hago debug, pero si la pongo a correr normal (sin debug) me aparece el siguiente error:

> Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer}

Mi petición http get esta de la siguiente manera:

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.170/app_dev.php/api/users/me");
  request.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+params[0]);
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  result = reader.readLine();
```

La misma petición la corri desde mi consola de ubuntu con CURL y funciona perfecto, por lo que la petición estructuralmente esta correcta.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿De dónde sale `params[0]`?

Comment: has comprobado que params[0] no sea nulo ?

Comment: Ya he comprobado que los parámetros necesarios para la petición estén correctos y el params[0] es un token.

Comment: @devjav prueba lo que comento en mi respuesta y comentanos que obtienes!.

Answer (score 0):

Este mensaje de error significa que el servidor respondió con el código de estado 401 (no autorizado) pero no proporcionó un reto de autenticación único (portador = WWW-Authenticate: Bearer), por lo que es imposible que HttpClient se recupere automáticamente del error de autenticación.

Lo más probable es que la aplicación espera un poco de credenciales en el formulario HTML incluido en la solicitud HTTP POST.

Nota: Como dato extra HttpClient es una libreria deprecada, usa HttpUrl Connection en su lugar.

Answer (score 0):

**Primeramente `HttpClient` es una clase obsoleta por lo cual te recomiendo usar [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).**

En cuanto a tu error definitivamente es un 401, comentas que esto sucede únicamente al ejecutar tu aplicación de forma normal, es un poco dificíl esto suceda si tienes las correctas credenciales o datos a usar en el header.

Me parece que el problema podría ser que la obtención de `params[0]` proviende de un proceso asincrono, por lo tanto al ejecutar tu aplicación de forma normal no obtiene el valor correcto. Te propongo agregues un `Log` y revises en tu `LogCat` que valor imprime cuando ejecutas normalmnete tu aplicación:

```
 Log.d("CONEXIÓN", "valor de params[0] : " + params[0]);  
 request.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+params[0]);
```

Comment: Comprobé todos los parámetros necesarios para ejecutar la peticion, estan correctos, pero mi problema sigue, en debug funciona perfecto, de lo contrario falla.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, la ip que esta en la url era lo que causaba mi conflicto, pero desconozco el motivo, lo que hice fue reemplazar la ip por la url de la app del cual quería extraer los datos, y con esto ya funciono.

Comment: si haces ping a la url se comprueba que sea la IP correcta

Comment: porque tenías una IP privada configurada como servidor...